# Does Delta PLC Modbus RTU support reading Input register?

Tags: input, modbus, plc, delta, rs485

I have DVP12SE11R PLC as master and Analog Input to MODBUS converter device as a slave. Analog Modbus stores the current data in Input Register 0x1 and 0x2. Delta PLC shows data read through Holding Register only. Is IR read FC04 not supported by Delta PLC?

Comment: Typically you won't get answers to hardware-specific questions on StackOverflow such as twiddling bits on a register level.  You're probably only going to find answers like that on the vendor's support forums.

Comment: I would be heavily surprised if it does not. This is a basic Modbus function 3x and 4x. Sometimes it lacks some functions like 16x or 21x but never those 2. So I would be 99.9% sure it does supports holding register.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb1Js.png)

Yes. I think it doesn't support FC04

Comment: Please attribute/disclose the source of the picture. Consider not showing it as picture of text and provide the info as text.